# OneLogin Error - Sequence Contains no elements

Tags: saml-2.0, onelogin

I am creating some POC for Single Sign On using One Login as Identity Provider. I am facing an issue currently.

I added an application created in ASP.Net MVC 4.5 using Owin, in One Login using WS-Fed for SAML2.0.

But I am getting the below error. The attached is the metadata received during the request. Below are the configurations setup in web.config.

When I verify the certificate I can see three URL’s. Please can you help on this.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Sequence contains no elements

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]

System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +415

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__1.MoveNext() in c:\workspace\WilsonForDotNet45Release\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions\Configuration\WsFederationConfigurationRetriever.cs:100

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +13892036

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__3.MoveNext() in c:\workspace\WilsonForDotNet45Release\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions\Configuration\ConfigurationManager.cs:0

[InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/560707'.]

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__3.MoveNext() in c:\workspace\WilsonForDotNet45Release\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions\Configuration\ConfigurationManager.cs:212

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +13892036

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +13892181

Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation.d__1f.MoveNext() +3191

System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31

Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation.d__1f.MoveNext() +5675

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +13892036

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61

Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +816

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +13892036

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61

Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +333

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +13892036

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61

Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +774

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +13892036

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61

Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +774

Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +96

System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +363

System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error it seems that you need to register the Onelogin IdP metadata: https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/560707

Comment: Hi I registered the app in the address. https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/560909 and when I enter the URL in the browser I can see the metadata.xml downloaded. But when I run the application it is throwing the same error.

Comment: The url that you registered is not the same than the one showed in the error. Notice the numbers at the end of the url. Maybe you registered a wrong metadata.

Comment: I deleted the application which shown error and now I created a new application http://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/560909, which is showing the same error.